# Completion handler never called

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a function like this.

```
class func getAccountBalances(completionHandler:@escaping ((_ balances:Any) -> Void)){
//Alamofire request and we get the result. But sometimes the result fails.
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        completionHandler(value)
    case .failure(let error):
        print ("error is: \(error)")
}
```

I am not putting code to handle the result if it fails. Is that a bad thing? Do I need to have a completion handler in the case that the call fails so that this function does not stay in the memory waiting for that completion handler to be called? What is the best practice?

Comment: What type of object is your response.result and does it return true for .success(response.result) in a test?

Comment: JSON and normally it does return true but sometimes it fails. I am using codable to parse it.

Comment: Wait sorry I think I misread your question, are you asking for advise on coding standard or is your success case not getting called at all?

Comment: I am asking for advise on coding standards. I am basically asking if it is bad practice not to include a `completionHandler(value)` if the `case .failure` is called or should I change `(_ balances:Any)` to `(_ balances:Any?)` and have  `case .failure(let error):
        completionHandler(nil)`?

Comment: @NevinJethmalani add a second parameter (`Error?`) to your completion handler. Day you really need to return `Any` ? If so change it to `(Any?, Error?)` otherwise better to return the correct object type `Balance?`

Comment: @NevinJethmalani am I right to assume that you are passing the completionHandler closure in the completion handler for your Alamofire request?

Comment: FWIW, not only would I suggest making `balances` an optional, but I'd question the decision to make it `Any` in the first place. Do you really not know what the object being returned is. I'd generally make the closure `(Balances?, Error?) -> Void` so that you can return a `Balances` object if it's successful and return an `Error` object if not. Now, what type you use for this first parameter is a function of what you are returning, but using `Any` is a bit unswifty.

Comment: @Rob So this was just for the sake of the sample. I am still a little confused on making self weak. I have seen this done before but never really understood the purpose of it. When do we need to do this and we don’t we need to do this?

Comment: There are two considerations: If there's a risk of a strong reference cycle (where you store this closure as a parameter and never release it), then absolutely use `[weak self]`. But that's a non-issue with Alamofire, because they release the closure when they're done with it. (Look on the Alamofire page and they rarely/never use `[weak self]` pattern, because it's simply not needed.) The other concern is more trivial: If you issue a request and happen to dismiss the view controller before request finishes, do you care if it hangs on to the view controller until the request finishes or not?

Comment: ... Generally you don't care, so you don't bother with `[weak self]`. But if you do (e.g. if the view controller takes up a lot of memory or if the request could likely be very slow), then by all means you can use `[weak self]` to let the view controller be deallocated as soon as its dismissed. So Radu is right that you _can_ use `[weak self]` pattern, but in the case of Alamofire, it's often a non-issue. And I certainly didn't want you to be worried about using `[weak self]` to prevent leaks in this particular case. But you can use that pattern if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is a good practice to call the completion on every case. The reason for this is that you usually want to let the upper lever(business logic layer) decide if it should mark some balances(for example) as saved, or maybe show a dialog when an error has occurred. That is a good practice with the thinking that everything should be a module. That being said, if another module will want to call the same function at some point, it may be a good thinking to let that module what happened with the result. That can be implemented in several ways, I won't enter here, it's your decision.

However, it's not a must to do it. If a block won't be called it *should* be deallocated, and then everything is good memory-wise. So in your example, if you don't retain the block somewhere else(for example holding it in a variable inside the class that makes `getAccountBalances` call), you should be just fine.

Another important part is when you call the function be careful to not create a memory leak where you retain the `self` inside the block:

```
getAccountBalances() { _ in 
   self.updateUI()
}
```

This block will create a retain to self and if everything goes okay with the call, but user left the screen, you may end up using variables that were deallocated and crash the app. A good practice here is to not retain the self in the callback, but make it weak before that:

```
getAccountBalances() { [weak self] _ in 
   // This is not necessarily needed, and you could use self?.updateUI() instead. 
   // However, this is usually another thing i like to do and consider it a good practice
   guard let `self` = self else { return }
   self.updateUI()
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks! Can you elaborate more on the memory leak part? I think I might have this problem in my code. What is the best practice here? What exactly should I be doing to avoid the leak?

Comment: @NevinJethmalani let me know if I should put more details. If you need more help with a certain situation, I advise you to post the whole scenario

Comment: Just to clarify: Radu, I suspect you know this, but for the benefit of @NevinJethmalani, if you don't use `[weak self]` pattern in conjunction with Alamofire, it won't "leak" per se, but merely might wait a few seconds to deallocate the view controller after it's dismissed, merely waiting for the request to finish. Sometimes you want `[weak self]` pattern (if you're merely updating UI), but in other cases you may be updating model or the like and in that case, you do not want to use `[weak self]` pattern. It just depends upon what you're doing in this closure.

Answer (score 0):

Your title: **Completion handler never called**

Your code: does not return any value to the completion handler if there is an error.

How would you expect to see a result of the competion handler if there is a failure? Would you like to crash the app? This way is better because it handles both cases:

```
class func getAccountBalances(completionHandler:@escaping ((_ balances:Any?) -> Void)){ //make Any an optional
//Alamofire request and we get the result. But sometimes the result fails.
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        completionHandler(value)
    case .failure(let error):
        print ("error is: \(error)")
        completionHandler(nil)
}
```

Your new call to this function:

```
getAccountBalances() { value in 
guard let _value = value else { // anticipate on the error return }
// use _value, the balances are inside.
}
```

An other approach would be not making it nil, but downcasting the value inside of it. That would look like this:

```
class func getAccountBalances(completionHandler:@escaping ((_ balances:Any) -> Void)){
//Alamofire request and we get the result. But sometimes the result fails.
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        completionHandler(value)
    case .failure(let error):
        print ("error is: \(error)")
        completionHandler(error) //notice this change
}
```

Then your function would look like this:

```
getAccountBalances() { value in 
if let error = value as? Error { //or whatever type your error is in the function
  //there is an error
}
}
```

Comment: what happens if I don't include the `completionHandler(error)`? Does the function stay in the app's memory and cause issues later on or is it ok to do that? I don't need to do anything in the main VC if there is an error. I just ignore the error anyways.

Comment: @NevinJethmalani why do you even want to to this? your function will wait for a return but that return never comes. I think it would stay in the memory, but I would not really know that. But there is no reason I could think of to not return a value in an escaping completion handler.

Comment: yes that is all I wanted to know. there is no reason. just once in a while I will forget to handle the error so I wanted to know if it was a big deal or if I should go back and add that line of code to handle the error.

Comment: You mean `Error`. You can't cast it to its own instance. `if let error = value as? error {` will always fail